# Extracting data from a column in a csv file based on data from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that contains 300 customer ticket orders. There are 4 columns (customer id, day of attendance, amount of tickets bought, method of purchase (college website or college reception)). The tickets for Wed and Thur are £5 and Fri tickets are £10. The first row looks like:- c001, F, 7, W. How do I get the program to look through column B for Friday entries and calculate all of the tickets bought in column C, but only from the rows that contain F in column B?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would want to use the [pandas package](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/#) in your case.
Then you can do what you want using (or at least how I understood it):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(file_path)
friday_df=df[df["day of attendance"]=="F"
nr_sold=friday_df["amount of tickets bought"].sum()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas. My understanding of Python is pretty basic. I'm learning it at college.